# JavaScript undefined throws TypeError

Tags: javascript, undefined

i am now learning javascript and found some problems with this code

```
var response = '{"status":{"message":{"-1":[111]}}}';
response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
if ( typeof (response.status.warning[-1]) == "undefined" ) {
    console.log(true);
};
```

why he throws a error, instead of just ignoring "console.log" part?

[image: dafuq is this javascript]

Comment: try change `response.status.warning` to `response.status.message`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to code this more defensibly:

```
if (response && (!response.status || !response.status.warning || typeof (response.status.warning[-1]) == "undefined" ) {
```

Checking the existence of `response.status` and `response.status.warning` should be done.  If `response.status` doesn't even exist, `response.status.warning` will generate an error

Comment: Is there possibility to avoid printing object to console if "if" statement is false, without adding "else" ?

http://i.stack.imgur.com/m3WNC.png

Comment: Update, object was printed only if u run script in console, tried on "live", everything is ok.

Comment: So does that mean it worked? Or are you still having problems?

Comment: I am checking my monitoring service, if until 18:00 i will not notice this error again, i will check your answer as a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Because it can't even get through this part:

```
typeof (response.status.warning[-1]) == "undefined"
```

since `response.status.warning` is `undefined`. That's why it throws an error.

---

To check if `response.status.warning` exists only when you are sure that `response` and `.status` are not `undefined`:

```
if(response.status.warning){
    console.log("It exists!");
}
```

Comment: I ve changed message to warning on purpose, i want to check what will happens if in response will be no "message"

Comment: @Nerfair `response.status.warning == undefined` will check if it exists or not.

Comment: Javascript doesn't like to access properties of undefined objects. that's why you should always make it a habit to check for the existence of the property before you access it. The other answer covers this point.

Comment: @sweetamylase - But since it is jQuery then `response` and `.status` should always exist according to the doc.

Comment: Irrelevant in this case, See in his example, he's converting the string *'{"status":{"message":{"-1":[111]}}}'* into JSON object.

Comment: @sweetamylase Oops, I was assuming that the object is returned by a jQuery function. Thanks for pointing that out.